# Mixed object / array iteration

Tags: php, object, iterator

I need a way to iterate any array or object ($this->_data).

The current draft is following:

```
class values implements \Iterator{
    private $_data = null; // array or object
    private $_keys = [];
    private $_key = false;
    // ------------ \Iterator implementation
    public function current(){
        return $this->get($this->_key);
    }
    public function key(){
        return $this->_key;
    }
    public function next(){
        $this->_key = \next($this->_keys);
    }
    public function rewind(){
        $this->_keys = [];
        foreach ($this->_data as $k => $v){
            $this->_keys[] = $k;
        }
        $this->_key = \reset($this->_keys);
    }
    public function valid(){
        if (false === $this->_key){
            return false;
        }
        return $this->has($this->_key);
    }
}
```

The problem is that i do not want to hold additional array for keys.

**May be there are some better way to iterate keys of an object avoiding additional abject/array creation for this purpose?**

(External iterator is not an option because i do not want extra object creation in a foreach loops)

Example of mixed usage with native myClass::methods and wrapper's values::methods

```
class myClass{
    var $x = 'x';
    var $y = 'y';
    public function hello(){
        echo 'Hello, '.$this->x;
    }
}
$a = new myClass();
$values = new values($a);
foreach ($values as $k => $v){
   $values[$k] = $v.' modified';
}
$a->hello();
```

**Additional notes:**

- values instance can be reused (by replacing $this->_data)
- usage of this class can be very intensive (from 100 to over 100000 different objects/arrays passed)
- values can be used and/or changed outside of values wrapper (see example above)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to implement `Iterator` on your own in a way that you don't need to store `$keys` separately (I can show if you want) you can just use or extend the class [`ArrayObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php). It looks like it perfectly fits your needs.

Check this example:

```
$a = new ArrayObject(array(
    'a' => 'foo',
    'b' => 'bar'
));

foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    var_dump($k, $v);
}
```

Output:

```
string(1) "a"
string(3) "foo"
string(1) "b"
string(3) "bar"
```

Comment: ArrayObject can't be used because values can be bound to some certain class instance. And this object can have methods that are using the same values.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't get you. (Maybe give an example?)

Comment: Btw, there are no problems with arrays: with arrays i have key() and next() functions.

Comment: added example for mixed native/wrapper methods usage

Comment: Why do you need the `values` class? you can directly iterate through objects of `MyClass` (once implemented)

Comment: I know. Iteration is not a main goal of this class.

Comment: What about this: http://3v4l.org/O2SR4 ? (But you can already iterate through public properties of any object in PHP)

Comment: I do not like the idea of new object creation in every foreach loop. Can be a problem with nested foreach. (I wrote a notice about this in question text: "External iterator is not an option")

Comment: My solution does **not** create a new iterator on each foreach. The iterator will being created just once the `values` object gets initialized.

Comment: I even have modified it to public function getIterator() {
        if (null === $this->iterator){

Comment: but there's no big difference, I want to avoid additional object/array creation

Comment: I'll be AFK for while (dentist). I have to admit that I still don't get the problem. Maybe you take some time to elaborate on the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.5.0+

Well, it actually fails, because it will create Generator instance at every call

```
class values implements IteratorAggregate{
    private $_data = null; // array or object
    public function __construct($data = null){
        $this->_data = $data;
    }
    private static function g($data){
        foreach ($data as $k => $v){
                yield $k => $v;
        }
    }
    public function getIterator(){
        return self::g($this->_data);
    }
}
```

Wish some alternative for php 5.4